# ng-repeat does not update table display when changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The table in my html form does not display values when it is updated. Here is the code:

```
  <div ng-controller='PersonalActionFieldController'>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Personal Action Field(from Infor-Lawson)</th>
            <th>Form Fields</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <select ng-model="name" ng-options="item.actionParam for item in actionFields"></select>
            <tr ng-repeat="action in actionFields">
              {{action.actionParam}} 
            </tr>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function PersonalActionFieldController($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.$watch('actionTypeName',function(newActionTypeName) {
    alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
  $scope.actionFields = null;
  $scope.httpData = '{"actionName":"'+$rootScope.actionTypeName+'"}';

  $http.post('http://localhost:82/rs/transformTrigger/lawsonFields', $scope.httpData)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.actionFields = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     //  Do some error handling here
     alert('error');
  });
});
```

}

Comment: You have a `select` inside the `tbody` but outside the `tr` - that's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an angular problem but the usage of the DOM elements: The permitted content of a tbody tag are zero or more tr elements, not a select. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

What about putting the select outside the table or inside a tr tag

Comment: I've just seen tymeJV answered this